# Implementing OAuth2.0 in FastAPI on AWS Fargate with ALB and Cognito - Trouble accessing API endpoint programmatically

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, load-balancing

We are building API framework for Open Banking in the AWS Cloud. As web server we have chosen FastAPI of Python that is running on ECS Fargate. To reach it using ALB )Application Load Balancer). Problem in implementing OAuth2.0 standard. Trying to use Cognito on top of ALB to authorize users via Cognito IdP.

Problem in ALB Cognito sessions, I can not understand how to reach ALB API endpoint in programmatic way. When I am using UI, ALB creates cookies of sessions AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0 and AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-1 after successful authentication in Cognito. But how to reach API route using Postman or Python because after receiving authorization access token in any way I got Cognito login page instead of FastAPI response (using it in header like Authorization:Bearer {token}).

Could you provide correct way how to work with ALB Cognito sessions in machine-to-machine way after user was authenticated via IdP?

Comment: I'll soon be tackling this same issue, but I don't have the infra setup yet to test. However, based on the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html#authentication-flow), if the cookie is not present in a request to the ALB, the ALB will redirect the user to the IdP authorization endpoint so that the IdP can authenticate the user. This leads me to believe that you can provide the cookie in your request after first obtaining it through a login. The ALB then validates the cookie and will redirect to your target API.